# WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider

in my asp.net mvc projet, i tried to implement a membership provider to manage accounts and roles

i'm facing this stack

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
```

acually i added this ligne to my Startup.Auth.cs

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); in order to allow
```

i tried to change my global.asax.cs as bellow

```
using decidata.mennilik.Models;

using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Optimization;
 using System.Web.Routing;
 using WebMatrix.WebData;


namespace decidata.mennilik
{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();


    }
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

but i'm having a problem in 
      AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
did i miss something ?

Comment: Could you give more details about the problem you have with AuthConfig? Also, post your AuthConfig.cs code.

Comment: i cheked out myAppStart folder and i don"t have any AuthConfig.cs file, i tried to create a new web MVC5 project but no AuthConfig.cs file !!

Comment: i added the file manually by creating a new classe but i still having Error "The name 'AuthConfig' does not exist in the current context" error !

Comment: The default MVC5 template doesn't use SimpleMembership. If you added this yourself then the AuthConfig may not exist.